# Auto screen rotation Dell Inspiron 7347

Tags: inspiron, onscreen-keyboard, display-rotation

I have purchased this notebook and decided to use linux on it. The problem is the auto screen rotation and the Keyboard.

In windows, when I turn it to tablet mode, it enables the on-screen keyboard and also auto-rotates the screen.

I read in this topic link [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/STMicroelectronics_LSM303DLH_Accelerometer/Magenetometer) and [here](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/owners-thread-dell-inspiron-13-7347-2-in-1.767645/page-3) that there is a batch script for this, but I have no clue on how to do that and if that will work on ubuntu (I'm new to linux).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded 16.04 to 18.04 and i faced same issue. Screen rotation automatically.
So i tried basic solution. Go to **Displays->Resolution** and change screen resolution **1366*768(16:9) to 1360*768(16:9)**. Now my system is working fine.